# Fix eclipse error

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

One of my Eclipse plugins has an error, visible in Product Configuration.  The plugin is:

Resource Monitoring Common Feature (Incubation):
[image: Eclipse error]

I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this.  Looked for a way to reinstall but all the product configuration lets you do is disable/enable.

Under Properties / Status for that item it says:

> The feature is not configured properly
>
> Reason: Plug-in "org.apache.commons.httpclient" version "3.1.0.v20080605-1935" referenced by this feature is missing.

This is preventing me from using new plugins (namely Adobe Flash Builder 4 beta 2).

Thanks, Trevor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to download the specified plug-in from Eclipse Orbit (the two-year old version is here: http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R200709171314/ - it contains the version you need).

If you are using Eclipse 3.3 (as I think about your screenshot), your only way to manually install it is to copy the jar file into the «eclipse install»/plugins folder, and restart Eclipse with the --clean (or -clean, I'm not sure) parameter.

If you are using Eclipse 3.4 or 3.5 (which is recommended if you do not have any specific reason to use an unsupported version), you could copy the file to the dropins folder and simply restarting Eclipse.